# Strange system app called Helper eating too much battery , data , CPU and freezing device

Tags: battery-life, battery-history, cpu

My phone usually work well until recently it turned out that battery gets really hot and camera Section that the phone starts popping that I should remove battery . when I look at battery usage I realise that Helper was the second after screen . what is even strange is that it is not found in system apps but there's no way to uninstall it .can only force stop and disable. But that doesn't help as though disabled , it still wakes up and I have to keep force stopping a disabled app.
It doesn't want me to connect to WiFi . A soft reset doesn't do anything only a hard reset does .but once I start reinstalling my apps it starts again .All my apps are from play store and i m no longer using beta apps . 
Also the app is not package helper . what's this  app and how can I stop it 
Device is android 6.0 unrooted

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's certainly not a helper ;). This is with no doubt a malware that has installed itself as a system app. If this is the case, you'll ne to be rooted to be able to remove it.

Comment: There's just no way to identify the app to uninstall it with root. It is not found in system apps under setting /apps/show system apps. Even es file explorer can't locate it under system apps

Comment: I wonder why it's even using so much data. Is there a way to see its data packets traffic without root?

Comment: The app is there, you need to know its package name. Try finding it with `Uninstall` (a system apps remover) - Download from Google play.

Comment: Thanks so much. Was able to find the app. Will be rooting the device and get rid of it. Thanks